# How to compute V statistic and statistical test in wilcox.test

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

```
x <- c( 9, 5, 9, 10, 13, 8, 8, 13, 18, 30)
y <- c(10, 6, 9,  8, 11, 4, 1,  3,  3, 10)
wilcox.test(y, x, paired=TRUE, exact=FALSE, correct=FALSE)
```

How do you compute the $V$-statistic and statistical test in R's `wilcox.test()` by hand? I need the algorithm, but I cannot find relevant materials about the formula.

Comment: Did you try `?wilcox.test`? Or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test)?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. The ouput from `wilcox.test()` prints the V statistic clearly. In your case, `V = 3`, so what are you asking?

Comment: I want to compute V statistic and P-value by hand. I need algorithm.

Comment: Perhaps you should form your fundamental problems with this dataset and test into one complete question covering the reasons why you're asking and what you've tried. This would be much better than asking multiple questions with the same code that really aren't getting at what you really need to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fine, let's do this. Following [the instructions on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test#Test_procedure):

1. Exclude the third pair because it's a tie.
2. Order the absolute values of the differences: {1,1,2,2,4,7,10,15,20}

   - (they happened to be in order already)
3. Rank them, averaging ranks for ties: {1.5,1.5,3.5,3.5,5,6,7,8,9}
4. Multiply these ranks by the signs of the corresponding pairs' differences {-,-,+,+,+,+,+,+,+}
5. Sum them: -1.5 - 1.5 + 3.5 + 3.5 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 39 = *W*

   This actually was a little confusing. [It looks like *V* is just the sum of the ranks that are positive in step 5.](http://statistic-on-air.blogspot.com/2009/07/wilcoxon-signed-rank-test.html) Thus *V* is either 42 or 3, depending on the order of inputs. With `y` before `x` as you have it, *V* = 3. My math in step 4 subtracted `y` from `x`, which would give *V* = 42 instead, just like `wilcox.test(x,y,paired=T)`.

Comment: Thanks. I have found algorithm. here: http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rsignrank.pdf

Comment: The algorithm of signed rank S statistic in SAS would be find here. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/63104/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_univariate_sect029.htm